# Need help with circuit design

Tags: operational-amplifier, thermistor

For the class I am taking, we are to design a circuit with a thermistor in a wheatstone bridge. When the thermistor senses a temperature above 100°F or below 60°F it is supposed to turn on a red LED otherwise a green LED is supposed to be on. The circuit I have turns on the red LED at the 100° set point then turns on the green LED at the 60° set point. I am not sure how to fix that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

*Function table (to be edited by OP).*

```
Temperature   Green   Red
    < 60°F    Off     On
60 - 100°F    On      Off
   > 100°F    Off     On
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. You said "turn on a red LED otherwise a green LED", which suggests there is a single setpoint. If you need two setpoints, why not use two op amps?

Comment: You have two setpoints in that the reference voltage at PR10 changes with the state of the output, i.e. R9 is causing some hysteresis. Ramping the value of the thermistor up until it changes state, then back down will cause the changeover  to occur at different point.

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication. There is a temperature range we are supposed to use; for my circuit it is 60 to 100 degrees Fahrenheit. So above 100 degrees the red LED should turn on and below 60 the red LED should turn on. But between the two a green LED should be on. I would use two op amps like you suggest but I am unsure how to connect them.

Comment: Don't leave important information in the comments...fix your question. And add **all** of the information you can.

Comment: Thanks Elliot Alderson. I will edit my question.

Comment: Your problem is R9=500k pot feeds back a ratio of 9k/2=4k5 / R9 * +/-12V/5V voltage is too large and should only shift the V+th (threshold) by 1'F equivalent voltage. You could consider 400K in series with pot.

Comment: I've added a function table into your question. Please check that I have understood your specification correctly. The function table or truth table is usually much clearer than a load of text and will clarify your thinking about a possible solution.

Comment: You are correct with that function table.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact constraint, here is one idea with using two single ended, rail to rail output op amps and some transistors.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you are after is a **window comparator**.
Adjust R1,R2 and R3 to get the thresholds that you want.

The graph on the left describes the output with respect to the Vrefs (red horizontal lines) and the input voltage (blue line).

[image]
http://www.circuitous.ca/Comparators.html